# Universal Analytics, will this work: Remarketing + Anonymise IP?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

So I need to have this feature in Analytics code to anonymize IP from the visitors:

```
ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

But I also need remarketing for AdWords campaigns:

```
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
```

So my question is: will remarketing work with anonymize IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work. Remarketing does not depend on the IP address, it uses the (3rd party) cookie from the Google display network.